# Uncaught TypeError on getQueuedFiles() method used with Dropzone.js

Tags: dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js. It works fine until I use getQueuedFiles() method. Not sure what's wrong with my coding.

This is how I tried to get the queued files.

```js
 var test = myDropzone.getQueuedFiles();
```

and it doesn't work.

Here is my code.

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$(function ()
{
    var myDropzone =
    $('#inputImage').dropzone({
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        url: './images'
     });
  
    var test = myDropzone.getQueuedFiles();
    console.log(test);

});
```

Then I got this error:
"Uncaught TypeError: myDropzone.getQueuedFiles is not a function"

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I've figured out.

```js
var myDropzone = new Dropzone('#inputImage', {url: './images'});
```

Then, it works!